# Download large number of files with qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to download large number of files (not usually small) with qt (also calculate speed and display progress), currently i using QnetworkAccessManager for this, but on large number of fast downloads it's crashing randomly, most frequent ntdll.dll!tan on stack, google says it's from heap allocation from win api, i do not do any manual memory management in this code part so i think i can't do memory corruption by my code, i also tried to not delete qnetworkreply objects which is also did not solve crashes, here is code parts:

do request:

```
QNetworkReply *r =  qnm.get(req);
connect(r, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), SLOT(game_s_file_download_progress(qint64,qint64)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()), &conn_timer, SLOT(stop()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(game_sz_file_request_finished()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(r, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), &conn_timer, SLOT(start()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(r, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), spd_calc_obj, SLOT(handle_new_data(qint64,qint64)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
conn_timer_obj *ct = new conn_timer_obj(0, r);
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()), ct, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(&conn_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), ct, SLOT(abort()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(&conn_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &conn_timer, SLOT(stop()));
conn_timer.start();
```

(qnm is QnetworkAccessManager)

handle data:

```
lists_mutex.lock();
QNetworkReply *current_file = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
assert(current_file != NULL);
#ifdef DEBUG
try{
#endif

if(current_file->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    if(!updated_size_c_f)
        updated_size_c_f = updated_size_c_f_completed + bytesTotal;

    QString filename = cfg->game_path();
    if(!updated_g_s_list_http.empty())
    {
        filename += QString::fromUtf8(updated_g_s_list_http.begin()->name.c_str());
        if(filename.indexOf("/l10n/") != -1)
        {
            int p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
            p1 = filename.indexOf("/l10n/");
            p1+= strlen("/l10n/");
            p2 = filename.indexOf("/", p1+1);
            filename.remove(p1, p2-p1);
        }
    }
    else
        filename += QString("/upd/" + QString::fromUtf8(updated_g_f_list.begin()->path.c_str()));

    updated_size_completed_mutex.lock();
    updated_size_completed += current_file->bytesAvailable();
    updated_size_c_f_completed += current_file->bytesAvailable();
    emit set_progress2(((double)updated_size_completed/(double)updated_size)*100.0);
    QFile file(filename + ".upd_part");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append))
    {
        file.write(current_file->readAll());
        file.close();
    }
    else
        current_file->abort();
    if(!partial_pak_downloading)
        emit set_progress(((double)updated_size_c_f_completed/(double)updated_size_c_f)*100.0);
    updated_size_completed_mutex.unlock();

}
else
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    cfg->log()<<current_file->errorString();
#endif
    current_file->abort();
}
#ifdef DEBUG
}
catch(...)
{
    cfg->log()<<"exception in game_s_file_download_progres: ";
    lists_mutex.unlock();
}
#endif
lists_mutex.unlock();
}
```

and finished signal:

```
QNetworkReply *current_file = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
assert(current_file != NULL);
lists_mutex.lock();
current_file->disconnect();
conn_timer.disconnect();
QString filename = cfg->game_path();
#ifdef DEBUG
try{
#endif
if(!updated_g_s_list_http.empty())
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    upd_stats.incr_d_h();
#endif
    filename += QString::fromUtf8(updated_g_s_list_http.begin()->name.c_str());
    if(filename.indexOf("/l10n/") != -1)
    {
        int p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
        p1 = filename.indexOf("/l10n/");
        p1+= strlen("/l10n/");
        p2 = filename.indexOf("/", p1+1);
        filename.remove(p1, p2-p1);
    }
}
else
{
    assert(!updated_g_f_list.empty());
    filename += QString("/upd/" + QString::fromUtf8(updated_g_f_list.begin()->path.c_str()));
}
#ifdef DEBUG
}
catch(...)
{
    cfg->log()<<"exception in game_sz_file_request_finished part 1: ";
}
#endif
if(current_file->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    try{
#endif
        fail_dl_count = 0;
    int have_bytes = current_file->bytesAvailable();
    if(have_bytes)
    {
        updated_size_completed_mutex.lock();
        updated_size_completed += have_bytes;
        emit set_progress2(((double)updated_size_completed/(double)updated_size)*100.0);
        updated_size_completed_mutex.unlock();
        QFile file(filename + ".upd_part");
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append))
        {
            file.write(current_file->readAll());
            file.close();
        }
        else
            ;//TODO: handle error
    }
```

**UPDATE1:**

i have posted bug on qt bugtracker, it also have linked bugs with same problem:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25514

Comment: how many files do you download at the same time? 6 is the limit if i can remeber

Comment: i downloading not in parallel, but consequentially

Comment: maybe i must post bug to qt bugtracker ?

Comment: but what do you mean crash randomly? whatds the stack trace? does it say anything before dying? have you debuged it ?

Comment: yes, i working under debuuger, most often on stack i see something like
1. ntdll!tan
2. ??, if look on other threads i think crash somewhere arround internal events handling or qnetworkreply destructor i think...

Comment: some more info http://i35.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0416/53/84385b41793ee15f086ee29dae7ad253.jpg - screenshot of crash, also stack of threads http://pastebin.com/Ycgfs9Tq

Comment: could you please provide me with a better page for the picture. i cannot open that page up at work and feel good about it. sorry

Comment: http://sss.chaoslab.ru/screen.jpg direct link to my host, sorry i forget about all ads on fastpic, adblock and noscript removing it all

Comment: ok, i got stack which looks like usable, but it still do not give me any ideas how to fix this..., look on url http://pastebin.com/pebyRV3Z, http://sss.chaoslab.ru/screen27.jpeg, i already seen qurl on stack on crash, i have checked different versions of qt (4.7.2, 4.8.0, 4.8.1), problem exists with all versions.

Comment: i also have helper class to abort connection if no new data in choosen interval, it's just simple class derived from qobject with signal connected to qnetworkreply::abort and slot (which emits signal) connected to qtimer::timeout

Comment: Your example is too big and has too much code.  Try copying your project to another directory (or even better, create a temporary branch in git or whatever version control).  Then start chopping out files and pieces that aren't necessary to get the code to crash, until you find the minimum needed for the crash to appear.  http://sscce.org/  You may also find a tool like valgrind (or Windows equivalent) to be helpful.

Comment: are you allocating a new string and deleting it?

Comment: all i know is that I just made a application which uses 8 threads and uploads 41000 files at the time (where every file does 4 requests)

Comment: does not allocating strings manually

Comment: i have made some more research and found thet this crash happening after this kind of error (http://91.214.69.46/kyC31j/8e08164915e6d850802b7cea1f3e4bcf/paks/levels/common/mesh_textures_053.pak/light/structures/buildings/etc/bu_l_fossilhead_01a_001.dds.z)" 
"Óçåë ????????????? word with wrong codepage - "host", and this is not complete error message, so looks like it crashing on error, on getting error message, i printing code after message with this code QString("file ")+filename+" download failed with error "+current_file->errorString()+" code:"+QString::number(current_file->error());

Comment: correct error message should looks like "file e:/aion/upd/light/structures/buildings/dungeon/dungeon_lf4/bu_l_elimwall_01a_006.dds download failed with error Âðåìÿ íà ñîåäèíåíèå èñòåêëî code:99" (message in wrong incoding - "connection timeout")